# How to drop substring from variable names?

Tags: r

I have the following names of variables:

```
vars <- c("var1.caps(12, For]","var2(5,For]","var3.tree.(15, For]","var4.caps")
```

I need to clean these names in order to get the following result:

```
clean_vars <- c("var1.caps","var2","var3.tree.","var4.caps")
```

So, basically I would like to drop `(..]`.

Is there any automated way to do it in R?

I was trying to adapt `str_replace(vars, pattern, "")`, but not sure how to make `pattern` flexible because it could have different values between `(` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("\\(.*\\]","",vars)
[1] "var1.caps"  "var2"       "var3.tree." "var4.caps"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` and `purrr`:

```
stringr::str_split(vars, "\\(") %>% purrr::map(., 1) %>% unlist()
[1] "var1.caps"  "var2"       "var3.tree." "var4.caps"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option of using `gsub`

```
> gsub("(?<=)\\(.*\\]","\\1",vars,perl = T)
[1] "var1.caps"  "var2"       "var3.tree."
[4] "var4.caps
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate

- the first `(` (in regex `\\(`) in the string
- and everything that comes after it (`.+`).

Replace it with nothing (`""`).

```
sub("\\(.+", "", vars)

# [1] "var1.caps"  "var2"       "var3.tree." "var4.caps"
```